# Remove bucketing by date in Finder results

Tags: finder

I have sorted by `Size` but `Finder` still sub-buckets by `Date`: e.g. *Previous 7 Days* *Previous 30 Days* etc.  I need to have that sub-bucketing removed: how to do this?

[image]

*Update*  I am on `Mojave` and the `Finder | File` menu is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unselect "Use Groups" in Finder settings. Pls see the attached picture to see the exact setting.

[image: Finder settings]

Comment: I am on Mojave (updated the OP) and have a significantly different `File` menu : which version is yours for?

Comment: Those directions are for a Macbook on macOS Catalina. I checked my other Mac which is on High Sierra. That setting seems to be under Action->Arrange By->None in High Sierra's Finder if that is of any help.

Comment: That option (in both versions of macOS I mentioned) is available through the icons at the top of but inside the Finder Window, not the menu at the top of the computer screen (Mac menu at the top).

Comment: `Action` is not in Mojave's version it seems.

Comment: oh that's irritating. I use keyboarding and menus not a mouse

Comment: going to have to do another hunt for a better `Finder` that does not hate keyboardists

Comment: @javadba I noticed the same option also exists under the "View -> Arrange By" menu at the top of the screen on High Sierra and the keyboard shortcut is ⌃⌘0. It might be the same on Mojave.